# How to correctly separate vertex color data into the R channel on EEVEE?

Tags: shaders, vertex-colors

for some reason if I add (in the shader tree) the ATTRIBUTE>COL from the vertex color property and channel it to a separate RGB (only making the R channel plug into a ramp node and then to the shader to RGB) I´m not getting a monochromatic channel from the red channel on EEVEE. What I get instead is the red color in the viewport.

How can I correctly make the red vertex color output a mono channel in red?

Also, I´ve been trying the same approach using ambient occlusion and feeding it to a separate rgb node into other channel, but then I don´t get the expected results: If I get a greyscale value on vertex driven by the red vertex color channel I want to multiply it using Ambient occlusion.

It is possible on Modo, Max and Softimage. What am I missing to do on Blender?
Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Here I am trying the monochromatic channel "fac" but if you do this on eevee 2.81 from the COLOR attribute node into image on separate RGB, you´ll get color on viewport. Please confirm if this is a bug or an expected behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the mixRGB node set to saturation? The second color can just be grey.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I need someone to confirm if this is either a bug or an expected behavior on viewport, as well.

Comment: The nodes you're showing above should be grayscale. First, the attribute node should send grayscale out through the Fac output, then separate RGB should send a grayscale out through each channel, and color ramp should map whatever input value it gets to whatever value you set it to, in this case black or white. Even if you plug a color input into a ramp, you should get grayscale if the ramp values are grayscale.

Comment: Yes sir, this what you mention is "expected behavior" on the viewport. Now, if you test it out on eevee, you´ll get a red channel on eevee viewport. Why? Could you please try and paste a url image to see your results, please? Thanks.

Comment: I can't put an image here in the comments, but what you've got is a bug if it isn't what I described. In my Blender, only when the Color output is hooked directly to the color input do I get color. In every other case I get grayscale: directly from Fac, from color to separateRGB, fromcolor to separateRGB to colorRamp.
To reiterate, using the node setup you show, I get grayscale. You should too, unless you've found a bug. For 2.80 and 2.81
Why ask on stack exchange if you have a bug, though? Blender has a bug tracker.

Comment: You can use imgur and paste the link for your image. Bug was reported 1 week ago. I just want to make sure this is working on eevee. Like I said: I am looking to paint red vertex, get it as a factor (mask) and turn to eevee to see that factor mix between any other 2 shaders/colors. What if instead of red we have green? Well, it will still show red on eevee render viewport. Would you like to try it, please? Thanks

Comment: I did try it out. I can't use imgur, but here's a link: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ87Xc7ZWIdx0ygKlDfMSxFCl3UK60UPA3MV I don't get the red that you're describing under any circumstances, unless I plug the red into a combineRGB node's R input(not shown).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug at a specific release of Blender - now unable to replicate the problem so it would appear that this has been long since fixed.

Comment: It works now. Indeed. But I even recorded a video about this issue. Great things the devs cleared this out

Comment: Great - glad it’s resolved. I added the answer to remove it from Unanswered list.